# Guitar bridge resonates wherever I play a C#

Tags: guitar, bridge

I have an Ibanez Gio and no matter where I play a C# it causes my guitar bridge to resonate. Please see my example attached to sound cloud where I alternate playing a C# on the G and D string.

https://soundcloud.com/cameron-ward-150102703/brdige-sound/s-omNyk

If I place my hand on the bridge I can stop this from happening, I cant do this every time I play though so my question is is there anything I can adjust on my guitar to stop this from happening?

Many Thanks
Cameron

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption it does this even without being amplified, there must be something loose on the bridge. I'd check screws and springs first, methodically working through each component. there should be nothing loose which will vibrate sympathetically.

Comment: Yes it does do this without amplification, I can’t seem to find anything loose, when it makes this sound the whole bridge vibrates, the entirety of the metal. I can definitely feel this if I put my hand on it and if I press hard enough it stops.

Comment: And you have checked the springs in the back @cameron? They can easily resonate. If they do, wrapping a rubber band round them can help.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem Ooh I haven't tried that, would it matter where I place the bands or not? I think they are defiantly part of the problem tho as they do seem to resonate.

Comment: I don't think it should matter Cameron. They just help damp unwanted resonance. I use rubber bands on three of my guitars that have "wolf tones" - my Gibsons and a Charvel - none of the others have the problem.